# C# Namespaces used as class equivalent

Tags: c#, namespaces

Does anyone come across with some older C# code as below, what would the equivalent in order to over come the later compiler error "'car' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'".

Many thanks in advance.

```
namespace something.car
{
  public class Display : UserControl
  {
    private car _car;  // comppiler error here
    public car carConfig  // comppiler error here
    {
      get
      {
        return this._car;
      }
      set
      {
        this._car = value;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `car` is a namespace in your example.

Comment: Don't name your classes the same as a namespace. Easy as that. You could probably alias the namespace to avoid that issue.

Comment: Is car a class in this example, Anywhere?
Reading your example as it is, you are trying to instantiate a namespace, which the compiler rightly points out can not be done.

Answer (score 0):

Change your first line from `namespace something.car` to

```
namespace Something.SomethingElse
```

and make sure you have a class `car` defined somewhere which you use in lines `private car _car;` and `public car carConfig`.

As a side comment, it is quite common to spell namespaces and class names in Pascal notation, e. g. `namespace Something` and `public class Car`.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use it without changing the namespace name ("but for sure change the namespace name is the right way").

but you can use the file path for the class when you use it, so if the car class is namespace "SomenameSpace.Viechels"

then you could use like below to not have the above conflict:
SomenameSpace.Viechels.car _car;
SomenameSpace.Viechels.car _carConfig;